# How to store all values in the key named folder using c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, io, key-value-store

I wrote a text file. The first item of each line from this text file supposed to be key and rest of the items are values. My text file looks like this-

```
Flensburg;Nordertor;Naval Academy Mürwik;Flensburg Firth
Kiel;Laboe Naval Memorial;Zoological Museum of Kiel University;Kieler Förde
Lübeck;Holstentor;St. Mary's Church, Lübeck;Passat (ship);Burgtor;Lübeck Museum of Theatre Puppets;Trave
```

For my project purpose, I need to create .json data for each values and store those vales into the key name folder.As I am very new handling this situation I am not getting the correct logic to do this. However I tried in the follwing way by which I can create the key name folder and and only one subfolder into it. But I need to create all values folder inside the key folder. How can I do it.

My POI class from which I read the  text file as key value is-

```
 public class POI
   {
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> poi = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    public bool ContainsKey(string key) { return this.poi.ContainsKey(key); }
    public List<string> GetValue(string key) { return this.poi[key]; }

    public void POIList()
    {
        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("POIList.txt"))
        {
            string[] parts = line.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            poi.Add(parts[0], new List<string>());
            poi[parts[0]] = new List<string>(parts.Skip(1));

         }

     }
 }
```

in the form1.cs

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            JSON_Output Json = new JSON_Output();

            Json.ToJsonForLocation(comboBox1.Text);

    }
```

also I set selectedindexchange from combobox2

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            POI poi1 = new POI();
            poi1.POIList();
            string txt = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            if (poi1.ContainsKey(txt))
            {
                List<string> points = poi1.GetValue(txt);
                comboBox2.Items.Clear();
                comboBox2.Items.AddRange(points.ToArray());

            }
        }
    }
```

now where the json file generated to sore the value is-

```
        public void ToJsonForLocation(string name)
        {
         var startPath = Application.StartupPath;
        string folderName = Path.Combine(startPath, "Text_ImageWithHash");
        string SubfolderName = Path.Combine(folderName, name);
        //string folderName = Path.Combine(startPath, "Text_ImageWithHash");
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(SubfolderName);
        string fileName = name + ".json";

        var path = Path.Combine(SubfolderName, fileName);
        var Jpeg_File = new DirectoryInfo(startPath + @"\Image\" + name).GetFiles("*.jpg");

        POIData Poi=new POIData();
        Poi.Shorttext = File.ReadAllText(startPath + @"\Short Text\" + name + ".txt");
        Poi.GeoCoordinates=GeosFromString(startPath + @"\Latitude Longitude\" + name + ".txt");
        Poi.Images=new List<string> { Jpeg_File[0].Name};


        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Poi,Formatting.Indented);
        File.WriteAllText(path , json);
    }
```

This is my code output while running the program.
[image: Window form picture]

after clicking button 1 Text_image_withHash folder is generated in the configuration directory.

[image: Text_Image_withHash]

Now if I open the folder I can see fthe following folders which is the key value from text file
[image: Key Value folder]

After enable button 2 for combobox two the values folder is generated but not in the key folder.but as usual way in the Text_Image_withHash.

[image: key and values are generated in the same folder where]

But What I want to do is-[image]

Comment: It's a little bit unclear what you are asking, try to clarify your question.

Comment: I have to second, waht @die maus said. Your first paragraph does not add up to your second or at least in my head they have almost no connection. You could make clear at which point in your written code a specific thing should happen by using comments.

Comment: @Kevkong . I have the above text file. I have the city name and many interesting places name in the text file. for my project I have to get a json data from web api for every interesting location which will contain geolocation, short description and some other information. those will saved as JSON format as name of every value name. These those files should be saved automaticaly the key name folder which I create by my code. By I cannot do how to save automatically all values in the key name folder. I cannot handle the dictionary logic in this case.

Comment: The way i read the second paragraph is that you want to create a folder i.e. *"Flensburg"* with the subsequent sub-folders (*"Nordertor, Naval Academy Mürwik, Flensburg Firth Kiel"*) Your first paragraph refutes this and your code-example makes even less sense.

Comment: Can I share some code then may be it would be more understandable?

Comment: @Nowshin please edit your question with this information.

Comment: An example could help a lot.

Comment: Do I get it right, you want the logic to transform the string
`Flensburg;Nordertor;Naval Academy Mürwik;Flensburg Firth` into a directory structure like this:
`\Flensburg\\`

`\Flensburg\Nordertor\\`

`\Flensburg\Naval Academy Mürwik\\` etc.

Comment: @I added some more code in the question.can you please have a look

Comment: @Kevkong: I have added example what I want to do.Can you please check

Comment: If your question is truly about creating that folder-structure, then see my answer. Thank you for updating your question, there is no shame in providing 'too much information', it always helps somebody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just got my answer. This is the solution of the above question.

For POI Class :

```
public class POI
{
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> poi = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    public bool ContainsKey(string key) { return this.poi.ContainsKey(key); }
    public List<string> GetValue(string key) { return this.poi[key]; }

    public void POIList()
    {
        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("POIList.txt"))
        {
            string[] parts = line.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            if (parts.Length == 0)
            {
                // Empty line or similar.
                continue;
            }

            string cityName = parts[0];

            poi.Add(cityName, new List<string>());

            // Add the points of interest to local.
            var points = new List<string>(parts.Skip(1));
            poi[cityName] = points;

            var startPath = Application.StartupPath;
            string folderName = Path.Combine(startPath, "FinalJson");
            string cityDirectoryPath = Path.Combine(folderName, cityName);

            Directory.CreateDirectory(cityDirectoryPath);

               }

    }
}
```

the the json output class

```
 public void ToJsonForLocation(string CityName,string PoiName)
    {
        var startPath = Application.StartupPath;
        string folderName = Path.Combine(startPath, "FinalJson");
        string SubfolderName = Path.Combine(folderName, CityName);
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(SubfolderName);
        string fileName = PoiName + ".json";

        var path = Path.Combine(SubfolderName, fileName);
        var Jpeg_File = new DirectoryInfo(startPath + @"\Image\" + PoiName).GetFiles("*.jpg");

        POIData Poi=new POIData();
        Poi.Shorttext = File.ReadAllText(startPath + @"\Short Text\" + PoiName + ".txt");
        Poi.GeoCoordinates = GeosFromString(startPath + @"\Latitude Longitude\" + PoiName + ".txt");
        Poi.Images=new List<string> { Jpeg_File[0].Name};

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Poi,Formatting.Indented);
        File.WriteAllText(path,json);
    }
```

this is generated folder and file in this way-[image: imag1]

[image: image2]
The Final json file for all values
[image: the final json file]

Answer (score 0):

To create that kind of folder-structure, simply use a foreach-loop. And `String.Split`.

**Required usings:**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
```

**Example:**

```
// basePath can be anything
var basePath = "C:\Something";
// assume "info" is your CSV.
var infoParts = info.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

if (infoParts.Length == 0)
{
    return;
}

var rootPath = infoParts[0];

Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(basePath, rootPath));

foreach (var subPath in infoParts.Skip(1))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(basePath, rootPath, subPath));
}
```

Saving JSON-files into these directories could then simply be made by combining the paths in a similar fashion.

I would also suggest some sanitizing of your paths (such as replacing `'/'` and `'\\'` with `'_'` or `'-'`.

**Example implementation:**

```
public void POIList()
{
    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("POIList.txt"))
    {
        string[] parts = line.Split(new[] { ';' }, 
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (parts.Length == 0)
        {
            // Empty line or similar.
            continue;
        }

        string cityName = parts[0];

        poi.Add(cityName, new List<string>());

        // Add the points of interest to local.
        var points = new List<string>(parts.Skip(1));
        poi[cityName] = points;

        // basePath will have to be retrieved somehow. It's up to you.
        string cityDirectoryPath = Path.Combine(basePath, cityName));

        // Create a directory for the city.
        Directory.CreateDirectory(cityDirectoryPath);

        // Create sub-directories for points.
        foreach (string point in points)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(
                cityDirectoryPath, point));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more. As I am very new handling this situation. I where can I put your code. Thank you.

Comment: You can extrapolate the content of my code into your `POIList`-constructor. However, if I were you I'd keep this logic out of the constructor and add a `LoadFromDisk`-method instead. Edit: basically, instead of adding items to your dictionary, simply use `CreateDirectory` (my code example) instead.

Comment: I have added serial picture what I want to do. Can you please check and explain a little bit more. Because I am not getting your code

Comment: But What shoud I do, if I want to implement it in the  public void ToJsonForLocation(string name). class. I know this problem is very complecated. And in this way I think it is not working. I have to change everythings. I am just not getting my answer

Comment: Is this not what you wanted?

Comment: What I am getting from your code is that create all value folder according to the key name. But if want to store the generated .json file for values in the key folder then what should I modify. because at this moment the generated .json file is stored outside the key folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100757/discussion-between-die-maus-and-nowshin).